# Network Manager asks to unlock keyring after auto login

Tags: wireless, network-manager, keyrings, pam, auto-login

After updating from Precise to Trusty I get a popup requesting to unlock the keyring for Network Manager after each login (autologin is enabled). On the Internet people advise to make the connection available for all users or install `libpam-gnome-keyring`.

I did both and none helped to solve the problem. I know of the method to unlock the keyring by setting a blank password but this seems to be a bad solution in terms of security. I only want to connect to Wi-Fi without password check, not to unlock the keyring for everybody. :)